# Third party application cannot write to disk

Tags: third-party, sandbox

I downloaded this application: [Donkey Simulator](http://docs.donkeycar.com/guide/simulator/)

And after unzipping there should be an executable file but also a folder called "log", and once the application is running, new files are written into this "log" folder.

However this does not happen and they warned about this situation:

> If logs are not being generated you are probably running a version of
>   OS X that sandboxes untrusted applications. This prevents the
>   simulator writing to disk. To resolve this, move the executable within
>   the Applications folder.

Their solution of dragging the app into the Applications folder didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logs are indeed getting created. I executed the app on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199). I have verified the log creation by precisely following the steps documented on the linked [download web-page](http://docs.donkeycar.com/guide/simulator/). Three important instructions to take note of from the linked web-page:

1. > If logs are not being generated you are probably running a version of OS X that sandboxes untrusted applications. This prevents the simulator writing to disk. To resolve this, move the executable within the Applications folder.
2. > This simulator can create log data in the donkey tub format. This is stored in the log dir at the root of the folder next to the executable. On the mac you will need to browse the package contents to see this folder. If this folder is missing, no data will be recorded.
3. > Hit Auto Drive w Rec button.

Now, follow the steps as described below:

1. Double click the downloaded `DonkeySimMac.zip` file. It will extract `DonkeySimMac/donkey_sim.app` app bundle.
2. Move/copy `donkey_sim.app` to `/Applications` directory.
3. Run `donkey_sim.app` by right clicking (**please don't double click**) on the app icon. Upon first launch (**only**), you'll be presented with a dialog box stating

   ```
   "donkey_sim.app" is an application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?
   ```

   Click **Open** to launch the app.
4. Select your preferred Graphics options and hit **Play!**.
5. Start scene of your choice by double clicking.
6. Hit **Auto Drive w Rec** button.
7. You'll be able to see a running counter against the label **Log** in bottom left corner of the app window. This verifies that the logs are getting generated.

[image]

8. Once you are done, click Stop → Exit → Quit.
9. Navigate to `/Applications` directory.
10. Right click on `donkey_sim.app` and select **Show Package Contents**.
11. Double click to open `log` directory.
12. Voila! Your logs are here.

[image]

**Observation**: Log generation only works when either **Joystick/Keryboard w Rec** or **Auto Drive w Rec** option is selected. (Yes, keyboard is mistyped as Keryboard!).

[image]

Comment: Works for me.   It does, however, overwrite the previous log files each time it runs, tho.  Any way to get these timestamped or to get a new folder opened under log for each run?

Comment: @ShpielMeister The behaviour you are observing is due to the way the app is programmed. Likely salvage options would be to copy over the log files before every run or get in touch with the developer and request for the change in implementation.

Comment: What an amazing amount of work to make an application that’s poorly designed run. +1 for the effort. Why not make an Applications folder in your user folder and run the app there if it insists on user control over the App folder? Then the instructions might be - put the app in user apps, open with control - click one time.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try creating a new folder in the Applications folder (i.e. "Donkey Simulator") and then moving the application inside of that folder?

Answer (score 2):

From reading the Mac install instructions, once you unzip the downloaded archive file you have a folder you then move to (the root level) /Applications folder. However, if your account is a standard user account then you will not have write access to the /Applications folder or any of its subfolders. You can open the Get Info window for the /Applications folder and add your user account and give it Read & Write access then do the same operation on the Donkey Simulator folder you placed in /Applications, but add the additional step of clicking the gear icon pop down and select "Apply to enclosed items..." so that your read & write access is applied to the logs subfolder as well. This should solve the issue.